# Is it possible to inject a vuex store depending on the route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

The app I'm working on has multiple stores with modules inside. I would like to inject the store globally depending on the path route. Is this possible to do?

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
{ path:"/", component:Homepage},
{ path:"/Site", component:Sitepage}
], mode: 'history');

 new Vue({router, store }).$mount('#app');
```

I have each store in a list, e.g. `stores = [HomepageStore, SitepageStore];`

I tried combining the individual stores and making a whole store from it like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    HomepageStore, SitepageStore
  }
});
```

This shows a blank page with no errors, even though it shows the store data and the routes, it doesn't show any elements on the page. It doesn't help it already has modules inside. There are about 50 store files so I do not want to alter each one in case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Just to update I am using vue 2.6.12 and vue-router 3.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

I think your formatting isn't correct please try

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    homepageStore: HomepageStore, 
    sitepageStore: SitepageStore
  }
});
```

Accessing your stores can then be done with

```
this.$store.state.homepageStore....
this.$store.state.sitepageStore....
```

Or you could create a global variable that has multiple stores

```
window._globalStore = stores;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried your first option and changing to $store.state.homepageStore but this still shows up as a blank page. It shows the routes but does not show the components

How am I able to use window._globalStore with new Vue({router, store }).$mount('#app');

Comment: When adding things to window. you have access to them in your whole application.
Just call try logging in a component to see if there is anything in it. 
console.log(_globalStore);